# Scenario that requires to remove or by-pass the filestream's cache/buffer?

Tags: c#, .net, security, file-io, buffer

I am writing a small utility for securely erasing files. Currently, I propose two wipe schemes: *random* (fill files with garbage data then wipe) and *zeroes* (fill files with zeroes then wipe). I will add more schemes later.

There is the source code of the method (inspired by [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22736/Securely-Delete-a-File-using-NET)):

```
public void WipeFile(string filename, int timesToWrite, WipeScheme scheme)
{
    try
    {
        if (File.Exists(filename))
        {
            // Set the files attributes to normal in case it's read-only.
            File.SetAttributes(filename, FileAttributes.Normal);

            // Calculate the total number of sectors in the file.
            double sectors = Math.Ceiling(new FileInfo(filename).Length / (double)SectorSize);

            // Create a dummy-buffer the size of a sector.
            byte[] dummyBuffer = new byte[SectorSize];

            if (scheme == WipeScheme.Zeroes)
            {
                Array.Clear(dummyBuffer, 0, dummyBuffer.Length);
            }

            // Create a cryptographic Random Number Generator.
            // This is what I use to create the garbage data.
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();

            // Open a FileStream to the file.
            using (FileStream inputStream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
            {
                for (int currentPass = 0; currentPass < timesToWrite; currentPass++)
                {
                    // Go to the beginning of the stream
                    inputStream.Position = 0;

                    // Loop all sectors
                    for (long sectorsWritten = 0; sectorsWritten < sectors; sectorsWritten++)
                    {
                        if (scheme == WipeScheme.Random)
                        {
                            // Fill the dummy-buffer with random data
                            rng.GetBytes(dummyBuffer);
                        }

                        // Write it to the stream
                        inputStream.Write(dummyBuffer, 0, dummyBuffer.Length);
                    }
                }

                // Truncate the file to 0 bytes.
                // This will hide the original file-length if you try to recover the file.
                inputStream.SetLength(0);

                // Flush the stream.
                inputStream.Flush();
            }

            // As an extra precaution I change the dates of the file so the
            // original dates are hidden if you try to recover the file.
            DateTime dt = new DateTime(1901, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0);
            File.SetCreationTime(filename, dt);
            File.SetLastAccessTime(filename, dt);
            File.SetLastWriteTime(filename, dt);

            // Finally, delete the file
            File.Delete(filename);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // TODO
    }
}
```

The program seems to work fine, but I notice strange results when I do benchmark (I test on an external HDD, multiple times with a file that weights 592 MB):

- Wipe with random data: about 7 seconds to wipe, equals write speed of 85 MB/s, seems OK.
- Wipe with zeroes data: about 500 ms to wipe, equals write speed of **1.2 GB/s**! What? Impossible!

The last result is very curious, so I decide to **disable the deletion from the disk** to test if at least the writing is done correctly. For this, I comment `inputStream.SetLength(0);` and `File.Delete(filename);`.

Now, the results are following:

- Wipe with random data: about 9 seconds to wipe, equals write speed of 67 MB/s. Hm, a little bit slow, but OK because it uses `RNGCryptoServiceProvider` after all (which is slow).
- Wipe with zeroes data: about 7 seconds to wipe, equals write speed of 85 MB/s. **Better than previous and more realistic**!

Here's what **I think**: the writes are first done in a buffer in memory. Then, the buffer is written (flush) on the disk. This is explain why write only zeroes is faster than write garbage data: get random values is very slow. So much so that the buffer has time to be flushed to disk.

But when I delete the file right after, the file is simply deleted from the disk and the buffer (or part of it) is NOT flushed! Why? This is not useful because the file is deleted, or the buffer has not time to be flushed. I don't know.

So, what can I do? Is it possible and adequate here to disable all the cache? Or should I call `Flush()` in each iteration?

Oh and I give priority to safety over speed!

Comment: Probably `inputStream.SetLength(0);` will prevent that everything is Flush()' ed

Comment: Good point! I will test...

Comment: @DrKoch OK, you have right. I benchmark again with just this line commented and the results are goods! I think I can't do more to make this faster or more secure.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
inputStream.SetLength(0);
```

from your code.

Probably you have to open the file  a second time (after overwriting) to set its size to zero.